# Can you install drivers in a VM which will be used when the WIM is captured?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I am using Hyper-v and have configured my VM (installed company specific software etc) and I am now ready to create a WIM from it.

What I noticed after creating the WIM file and deploying it was that the drivers were not available for the hardware I was deploying the WIM on. For example the windows resolution was wrong and when I check device manager, the intel graphics driver was missing.

So, is it possible to install drivers for the hardware I will be deploying to on the VM and then capture the image? That way I do not have to do a windows update to get the drivers (they are already on the VM and in my WIM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your target system you can do the powershell command

```
Export-WindowsDriver -Online -Destination d:\drivers
```

This will export all drivers from that machine to the `d:\drivers` folder. Once you have that folder mount your image some place and you can do the command

```
Add-WindowsDriver –Path "c:\offline" –Driver "c:\someHardware\drivers" –Recurse
```

Where the image is mounted to `c:\offline` and the `d:\drivers` from the source machine was coped to `c:\someHardware\drivers`

**NOTE:** if you are using the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn475741.aspx) to capture the image you can import the drivers in to the "Out-of-Box drivers" so images you build will automatically have the needed drivers added to them.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I'll try the offline approach. However, if I used pnputil on a VM, would the be installed?

Comment: I believe pnputil is just the non power-shell version of `Add-WindowsDriver` without `–Path` passed in, i think they do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I initially did on the VM (ran PnPUtil), but then I could not see them in the device manager (as it is a VM). I then ran Get-WindowsDriver to check then with the target system but it was a pain to confirm. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to stage drivers, include them in the Windows driver store, which should make them available to hardware, nonexistent on your VM but present on a different machine you want to apply them WIM to. I have used this prev. and it worked w/o a hitch. No VM was involved but the injected driver survived Sysprep with Generalization and was available afterwards on different hardware.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772036(v=ws.11).aspx